# Por que mapas são mais "rápidos" que arrays?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo-de-busca

Sempre li e ouvi dizer que mapas são muito mais rápidos que arrays para buscas. Até que decidi ver o quanto e fiz um jsperf: http://jsperf.com/maps-vs-arrays/

O que eu gostaria é de entender quais mecanismos tornam a busca em mapas mais rápida, e por que.

edit: no jsperf acima, os valores no mapa são uma arbitrariedade. O que estou buscando mesmo são as chaves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A ideia é que o método `indexOf` irá **percorrer** cada elemento do array verificando se o valor corresponde, nesse caso o custo dessa função é O(N) [(veja aqui sobre essa notação)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_de_tempo#Tabela_de_complexidade_de_tempo_comum).

[Você pode verificar aqui](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/array.js#1307) no código do V8, que a busca é sempre incremental.

Já para o Hash, a chave é mapeada para o valor, ou seja, quando se faz a busca o que acontece é que o valor da busca é transformado em um índice (usando uma função) que é usado para para buscar o valor. Portanto o custo de acessar o valor de um Hash é O(1).

[Veja um exemplo de implementação de Hash](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Simple_example), onde a função usado é de módulo.

Answer (score 13):

Para procurar por um elemento em um vetor arbitrário é preciso percorrer os elementos do vetor um a um. Em um vetor de N elementos, isso significa que na média você vai ter que fazer N/2 testes para achar o elemento do vetor, o que pode ser bastante se o vetor for grande.

Por outro lado, o mapa Javascript é implementado usando uma [tabela hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), que é uma estrutura de dados especialmente desenhada para que a operação de busca de elemento seja rápida. Geralmente, o número de operações necessárias é constante ou logarítmico no número de elementos, ao invés de ser diretamente proporcional.

Um exercício interessante é fazer um gráfico mostrando os tempos das duas versões para diferentes números de elementos.

---

Quanto ao vetor, essa estrutura de dados é otimizada para acesso rápido a um elemento, dado um índice. Se você já souber o índice de um elemento, você pode acessá-lo diretamente usando `vetor[i]`, sem ter que fazer um indexOf.

Finalmente, se o seu vetor estiver ordenado com os elementos em ordem crescente, é possível fazer uma [busca binária](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search), ao invés da varredura linear, o que é bem mais rápido. É a diferença entre procurar um número de telefone em uma lista telefônica organizada alfabeticamente e fazer a mesma busca em uma lista toda embaralhada.

Comment: A resposta está correta, mas é bom frisar que em JavaScript essa "estrutura de dados otimizada para acesso rápido" não existe: arrays e objetos são implementados da mesma maneira. Ver [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30042/215) pra mais detalhes. Outras linguagens (ex.: C, Java) usam arrays pra representar arrays, e hashes pra hashes, aí dá diferença. JavaScript não.

Comment: mgibsonbr: Apesar de tudo ser semanticamente objetos com chaves strings, [as implementaçoes mais modernas usam, sim, vetores quando possível](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233814/are-javascript-arrays-actually-implemented-as-arrays). Por trás dos panos, elas detectam quando há chaves numéricas consecutivas e usam um vetor para elas e uma hash table pro resto. Em alguns casos vai até mais longe: por exemplo, o V8 tem implementções separadas para vetores de objetos (ponteiros) e vetores de double

Comment: Interessante saber disso, eu sempre pensei que - se fosse pra engine fazer alguma otimização - ela o faria baseada no protótipo do objeto (i.e. o tipo `Array`), e não no seu conteúdo. Mas isso que você falou - e as informações contidas no link - faz todo o sentido.

Answer (score 6):

Os mapas ou hashmaps possuem [um hash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash) o que permite localizar os seus elementos em O(1). Enquanto em arrays você precisa de procurar pelo elemento para poder executar.

Os arrays possuem um desempenho melhor que mapas desde que você saiba qual elemento quer acessar, pois por mais que os mapas possuem um acesso constante os arrays possuem acesso instantâneo caso chamados pelo seu índice.

Eu fiz uma [revisão no jsperf](http://jsperf.com/maps-vs-arrays/3) que mostra  justamente esse comportamento, verá que o **Arrays 2** é o mais rápido por acessar os elementos do array de forma direta.

Comment: Interessante que o Arrays 2 é mais rápido no Firefox, mas não no Chrome. Acredito que é porque a função de hash do Chrome deve ser absurdamente mais rápida que a do Firefox.

Comment: Rodei os testes no IE10. Resultados semelhantes ao Firefox, porém com o Arrays 2 ainda mais rápido que o maps. Interessante.

Comment: @Sim notei isso depois, sim parece-me que o hash do chrome é muito superior. Mas que o desempenho de arrays padrão no chrome deixa a desejar por comparação.

Comment: "os arrays possuem acesso instantâneo caso chamados pelo seu índice" isso só *seria* verdade se o motor JavaScript otimizasse os arrays para serem arrays mesmo, tal como nas outras linguagens. Mas pelo standard, arrays e objetos são praticamente a mesma coisa em JavaScript. Não tem diferença, nem mesmo na representação interna. Os índices de um array são strings, não inteiros.

Answer (score 6):

Tem algumas coisas incorretas no seu teste:

- Deixe a definição do objeto e array de fora do teste, no `setup`, para que o tempo da declaração e atribuição de valor não conte no teste
- Deixe o loop por conta do próprio jsperf
- Use o mesmo método de verificação da chave ou valor (no seu teste, você verificava se determinada *chave* existia no objeto, mas no array verificava se determinado *valor* existia nela).

**Como em JavaScript arrays são implementadas como objetos com pequenas alterações, uma busca por chave deve ser equivalente nos dois casos.** E isso é comprovado (no Chrome) pelo seguinte teste: http://jsperf.com/maps-vs-arrays/5.

Comment: Os valores no mapa são apenas uma arbitrariedade. A busca que estou fazendo é pelas chaves.

Comment: Então é isso aí :)